# Image carousel doesn't work (all images are shown) until I press the buttons

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, carousel

After loading the page carousel (`crew-slider`) shows all images and text overlaps. But when I click on the buttons carousel starts to work correctly.

Here is some code I have:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'crew-slider',
);
$crew_slider = new WP_Query( $args );
$x=0;
$i=1;
$a=1; 
echo '<div  class="dot-indicators flex" role="tablist" aria-label="crew member list">';
 while( $crew_slider->have_posts() ) : $crew_slider->the_post(); $x++;
 echo'<button aria-selected="'. ($x-1 ? 'false' : 'true') .'" aria-controls="crewarticle-tab-'. $a++ .'" role="tab" data-image="crew-image-'. $i++ .'" tabindex="'. ($x == 1 ? '0' : '-1') .'"><span class="sr-only">The crew element</span></button>';
endwhile;
echo '</div>';
while( $crew_slider->have_posts() ) : $crew_slider->the_post(); 
$a--;
$i--;
echo '<article id="crewarticle-tab-'. $a .'" class="crew-details flow" role="tabpanel" tabindex="0">';
echo '<div class="flow flow-space--small">';
echo '<h2 class="fs-600 ff-serif uppercase">'. get_field('ruolo') .'</h2>';
echo '<p class="fs-700 uppercase ff-serif">'. get_field('nome') .'</p>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<p class="text-accent">'. get_field('testo_articolo') .'</p>';
echo '</article>';
[$url_crewslider] =wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'large');
echo '<picture id="crew-image-'. $i .'">';
echo '<img src="'. $url_crewslider .'" alt="image-crew">';
echo '</picture>';
endwhile;
```

This is the script:

```
const tabList = document.querySelector('[role="tablist"]');
const tabs = tabList.querySelectorAll('[role="tab"]');
tabList.addEventListener('keydown', changeTabFocus);
tabs.forEach((tab) => {
    tab.addEventListener('click', changeTabPanel);
});
let tabFocus = 0;
function changeTabFocus(e) {
    const keydownLeft = 37;
    const keydownRight = 39;
    if (e.keyCode === keydownLeft || e.keyCode === keydownRight) {
        tabs[tabFocus].setAttribute("tabindex", -1);
    }
    if (e.keyCode === keydownRight) {
        tabFocus++;
        if (tabFocus >= tabs.length) {
            tabFocus = 0;
        }
    }
    if (e.keyCode === keydownLeft) {
        tabFocus--;
        if (tabFocus < 0) {
            tabFocus = tabs.length - 1;
        }
    }
    tabs[tabFocus].setAttribute("tabindex", 0);
    tabs[tabFocus].focus();
}
function changeTabPanel(e) {
    const targetTab = e.target;
    const targetPanel = targetTab.getAttribute("aria-controls");
    const targetImage = targetTab.getAttribute("data-image");
    const tabContainer = targetTab.parentNode;
    const mainContainer = tabContainer.parentNode;
    tabContainer
        .querySelector('[aria-selected="true"]')
        .setAttribute("aria-selected", false);
              
    targetTab.setAttribute("aria-selected", true);
    mainContainer
        .querySelectorAll('[role="tabpanel"]')
        .forEach((panel) => panel.setAttribute("hidden", true));
    mainContainer.querySelector([`#${targetPanel}`]).removeAttribute('hidden');
    mainContainer
        .querySelectorAll('picture')
        .forEach((picture) => picture.setAttribute("hidden", true));   
    mainContainer.querySelector([`#${targetImage}`]).removeAttribute('hidden');
```

Thank you

Comment: If "custom slider" means you wrote the JavaScript part for this yourself as well, then you need to show us that code. (And if it doesn't, and you are using an existing implementation, then you need to tell us which one.)

Comment: That doesn't look like you had written any code to properly initialize your slider in any way? If you only start doing the necessary things when the user clicks somewhere, then you must not wonder that they don't happen earlier ...

Comment: Your slider appears based on that only one of the slides does not have the `hidden` attribute set(?) - so either write some JS code and execute it on page load, that produces that situation; or add the `hidden` attribute to all but your first slide in your PHP code already.

Comment: What more initialization does it need? I can't tell what more your script does, that would have to be handled for the correct initial display here.